# Increase or decrease values over time

Tags: .net, vb.net

Having a bit of a brain fart to be honest, so I do apologize if this is a simple question with a simple answer!

I am trying to create an integer that will increase by value by + (and if possible, minus (so that it can fluctuate naturally)) over time through a timer. This is my current code:

```
If timer_temp_int = 0 Then
    timer_temp.Enabled = False
    lblRemaining.Text = "0"
    MsgBox("Please check the temperature of the heater")
Else
    'PROBLEM HERE
    Dim temp2 As Decimal
    temp2 = temp += 0.01
    txt_temp.Text = temp
    timer_temp_int -= 1
End If
```

So, what I did was I assigned a second variable so that the temperature can be increased (this btw, is pulled from a random array)

```
Dim rn As New List(Of Integer)
Dim temp As Integer
Dim rnd As New Random
rn.Add(80)
rn.Add(90)
rn.Add(100)
rn.Add(110)
rn.Add(120)
Dim randomValue As Integer = rn(rnd.Next(0, 5))
temp = randomValue.ToString()
```

I added the code:

```
Dim temp2 As Decimal
temp2 = temp += 0.01
txt_temp.Text = temp
```

but this appears to be the issue, as I get: "end of statement expected".
Would there be a way of getting this to perhaps fluctuate (randomly, if possible though this isn't a worry) by +/- 0.01 for every second of the 60 second timer. The reason for this is I am creating a temperature application as an assignment, so I need the temperature to fluctuate by +/- 0.01 as the application runs to simulate natural temperature fluctuation.

Comment: `temp2 = temp += 0.01` is two statements: `temp += .01` to increment temp, then `temp2 = temp` to assign it.  I could not quite follow the rest of the saga but that seems a lengthy way to incr or decr a variable

Comment: My apologies, I did the temp2 = temp += 0.01 to test something, it is actually temp += 0.01 (which counts FROM 0.01 and goes up) however I need this ADDING to the value that is pulled from the array (from which a random value is pulled)

Comment: Your temp2 variable looks useless, you could remove it.

Comment: `"end of statement expected".` would result from the 2-statement code, which is the question.  If you want it to add from the array, add from the array `temp += rn(x)`.  There is not a lot of context for that code, like the scope of the array (`Dim` can imply it is local, so maybe you cant access it elsewhere)

Comment: @the_lotus My apologies for the confusion, this has now been removed, please refer to the above comment:

Comment: @Plutonix think I get what you're hinting at, to clarify: the array is pulled on the form load, and set to a text box. This shows the current temperature based on the options of 80, 90, 100, 110, 120. THIS value should then be able to fluctuate +/- 0.01 (hope that makes sense?) Any further questions please let me know. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you want it to add/decr arbitrarily, get a random `RNG(0, 2)`  if the result is 0, add .01, if the result is 1 subtract .01

Comment: @Plutonix what a corker of an idea. I have done the following: '            Dim number As Decimal
            Randomize()
            number = Int(Rnd() * 2)

            If number = 0 Then
                temp -= 0.01

            ElseIf number = 1 Then
                temp += 0.01
            End If

        End If
        txt_temp.Text = temp'

Comment: Still getting the value as 0.01 (and counting up or down) can I get a way to add or subtract this from the already generated value of 80 - 120 (which is the BASE temperature set by the application)

Comment: the comment switched from the shiny new net Random class to the legacy BASIC Rnd+Randomize functions.  `Random.Next(0, 2)` will give you a random 0 or 1 - the equivalent of a boolean to pick adding or subtracting.  Make the Random object a form level variable though - use the same one over and over

Comment: @Plutonix this makes sense, thanks for the clarification - would there be a way to have this +/- the already generated array though? As currently this just sets the text box to 0 and will add or minus 0.01 so instead of 90.1 (for example) I would get 0.01

Comment: is each value supposed to fluctuate independently? (one can go up, another down?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the originally posted question, the error message is the result of:

```
temp2 = temp += 0.01
```

This is trying to combine 2 statements:

```
temp += .01
temp2 = temp
```

For the larger question, this code should allow each initial value to fluctuate.  I dont know if each is supposed to do so independently, so you might have to change part of this:

```
' form level vars:
Private RNG As Random()
Private currVals As Decimal() = {80D, 90D, 100D, 110D, 120D}
Private TBs As TextBox()
```

Then initialize the TB array in form load:

```
TBs = {TextBoxA, TextBoxB, TextBoxC, TextBoxD, TextBoxE}
RNG = New Random()
```

Now you can fluctuate the base values in a loop which can be called from a timer tick or whatever. The `TextBox` array is solely to allow the code to update the display in a loop, the values could also be mapped one by one *outside* the loop:

```
For n As Int32 = 0 To currVals.Length - 1
    ' next bool is an extension; same as RNG.Next(0,2)
    If RNG.NextBoolean() Then
        currVals(n) += 0.01D
    Else
        currVals(n) -= 0.01D
    End If
    TBs(n).Text = currVals(n).ToString()  ' update display
Next
```

UI Controls are horrible variables, especially in this case.  The text controls contain string, you are working with decimals.  So the code changes the array value and updates the control (which *seems* like what you are after).

If the change is supposed to be the same for all the values, just pick one `Boolean` outside the loop.  `NextBoolean` is an extension method, the long form would be:

```
Dim thisVal = RNG.Next(0, 2)   ' pick from 0 to 1
If thisVal = 0 Then
    ' add
Else
     ' subtract
End If
```

Or:

```
<Extension>
Public Function NextBoolean(RNG As Random) As Boolean
    Return RNG.NextDouble() >= 0.5
End Function
```

Comment: Absolutely superb answer. I appreciate your support and patience @Plutonix - have a virtual pint on me!